# /system/bin/sh: adb: not found

Tags: android

```
$ adb shell
# mkdir data/local/tmp/testjars
# exit
```

That works fine and gives no errors, but when I do:

```
$ adb push <project_root_folder>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk data/local/tmp/testjar/load.apk
```

I get the error:

```
/system/bin/sh: adb: not found
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

---

Im deploying my app on **Virtual devices** (**Nexus 5**).

> **Android Studio 2.2.3**
>   Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>
> **Windows 10**

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you are trying to run `adb` on the device itself. To push files start adb on the host computer. To disconnect your `adb shell` session type `exit`.

You can not run `adb push` on the android shell. You have to run it on the host computer.

If this is not the case, post the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Hi @Jonas Köritz. I just made an update to my question. I'm using Android Studio on Windows 10. I tried your suggestion, but to no success. I'm also deploying my app on a virtual device.

Comment: Where do you type `adb push <project_root_folder>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk data/local/tmp/testjar/load.apk`? The `$` implies this is a linux (or Android) shell.

Comment: I've tried it on both: doing it on Android Shell as well as on the host computer. On the host computer it gives the error: `adb: error: failed to copy 'F:/projects/android/android_studio/plugins/dexclassloader/PluginSample/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk' to 'data/local/tmp/testjar/app-release-unsigned.apk': secure_mkdirs failed: No such file or d
irectory`

Comment: `echo path` produces `/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin`

Comment: You have to run it on the host computer! The error says that there is no such file or directory, maybe the target directory does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your android sdk to your bash_profile shell script.

Open or Create ".bash_profile" in your root directory of account. And insert your android sdk path to path variable in "bash_profile" file.

like this

```
PATH=$PATH:HOME/bin:/usr/app/mysql/bin:/Users/your_account_name/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/your_account_name/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2
```

After input path, save file and reopen your command line application. If you correct add that path, you can excute/call "adb" command in everywhere.

Have fun!

---

I heard that you are using Windows OS for working dev.

So it looks like that you typed "adb" command in "adb shell" of android device. Android OS is based on linux os. "adb shell" command is way to enter the android device's os terminal enviroment. In this enviroment, you cannot use "adb" command. Because of "adb" is "Android Debug Bridge". bridge means that "adb" command helps to connect your working enviroment to android device's os. So after type "adb shell", you are in the android device's os and you cannot use "adb" command.

this is my case.

```
User-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ adb shell

shell@hammerhead:/ $ adb

/system/bin/sh: adb: not found

127|shell@hammerhead:/ $ exit

User-MacBook-Pro:~ User$
```

BR

Comment: Hi @Jinwoo Kim. I just made an update to my question. I'm using Android Studio on Windows 10. I tried your suggestion, but to no success. I'm also deploying my app on a virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when entering: adb forward tcp:12345 tcp:12345 The solution was.

Do Not open adb  shell

open cmd then type: cd .android/platform-tools

Then type commands from this level.

if your platform-tools are at another location assign cd there. Don't forget the dot it may or may not be in the directory name.

Open ADB Shell for Sell commands not for other commands. This is probably of the track for the above however this still could be of benefit.